# grpc golang/c++ generate once compile for everywhere

Tags: c++, go, protocol-buffers, grpc

Is it an ok approach to generate grpc code from a .proto for a system language like c++ or go, and maintain it as a part of source code assuming it's platform agnostic?

**Edit**
To be more precise, for a given version of the framework does the code generation process yield the same code for every supported platform (as the host)?

Comment: erm... Yes, it depends... vague questions can only ever yield vague answers

Comment: yes but you should also vendor your dependencies, to ensure the generated code is compatible with the version of grpc your project uses (i.e. pin a version of grpc in your Gopkg.toml)